# How to insert a text with special chars in mysql using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, special-characters

I am trying to insert a text in mysql database that contains special chars (example : 'é' )
the text is inserted and 'é' is replaced with '?'
i am using codeigniter active record

Can anyone explain to me how to do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What charset is your database using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the database using collation utf8_unicode_ci. Also for phpMyAdmin.
After creating the database click on the operations tab at the bottom
you can change the database to the utf8_unicode_ci.
For more information [Here](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/174539/#828765)

Answer (score 0):

Following points required for multilingual data insert:

- Create your database with collection **"utf8_unicode_ci"**. Basically this allows Unicode (multilingual), case-insensitive data to be saved in your database.
- Create your database table and make sure you have selected/written collection set to be **"utf8_unicode_ci"** for all the table fields.
- Now comes to codeigniter part and check your database config file with location as mentioned below

  **application/config/database.php**

Now please check & update charset & collection settings as mentioned below

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```