# Error Number: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xC9 CULT...' for column 'value' at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a problem with data storing into mysql from codeigniter. As per some topics in google I have changed my tables character set from "latin" to "utf8" and collation to "utf8_unicode_ci".

And in my db settings utf8 is set and also I have set charset to utf8 in header section of all my pages. But still I am unable to insert the data.

My Query was

```
"INSERT INTO `cib_import` (`company_id`, `partner_id`, `field`, `value`, `client_type`, `service_type`, `status`, `created_date`, `updated_date`, `error`, `flag`) VALUES ('5006', '314', 'client_name', 'CAFÉ de Limited', '1', '4', 0, '2014-08-28 12:12:54', '2014-08-28 12:12:54', 0, 184)"
```

Some posts in this stack overflow says é is an ISO-8859-15. Does I have to change the table charset again?

I do changed the settings in codeigniter. Actually the "CAFÉ de Limited" is in "ISO-8859-1" encoding. I tried to change the string from "ISO-8859-1" to "UTF-8" using the following code.

```
mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($string, "UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15", true));
```

But the character "É" is converted to "Ã‰". How stackoverflow changing the character encoding? In this post I wrote "É" and stackoverflow managed to save the character and able to return the same character.

Comment: Did you change the collation of the DB? If so you need to change the collation of the table also (and make sure all the VARCHAR fields has changed the collation also)

Comment: I didn't changed the DB collation. But I changed the collation of all columns to utf8_unicode_ci. If I change the Db collation, then it may effect the other tables right?

Comment: AFAIK only the new ones, the ones that already exists will maintain their current collation (but check it out :-)

Comment: pls check settings : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472973/how-to-insert-a-text-with-special-chars-in-mysql-using-codeigniter/25474410#25474410

Comment: @k10gaurav:  Those changes are already in my Db Config file.

Comment: hmm...Try to check your php file encoding(save as). http://wordpress.org/support/topic/utf8-problem-incorrect-display-of-special-characters-e-e-a-a-o-etc